# Operator norm of integral operator operator, bound from below

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f:C[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is given by $$f(u)=\int_{-1}^{1} (1-t^2) u(t) \ dt .$$
I managed to bound $||f||$ above by $2$ and so want to find a function such that $|f(u)|=2 $ or some sequence such that $|f(u_n)| \rightarrow 2 $. Any ideas? Is the norm of $f$ even 2 because if not then obviously this won't work?

Comment: Should that be $u(t)$ in the integral?

Comment: It seems $\|f\|\leq\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: assuming you are using sup-norm

Comment: Which is attained for the constant function $u=1$.

Answer (score 4):

On one hand,
$$
\begin{align}
|f(u)|&=\biggl|\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)u(t)\,dt\biggr|\\
&\leq \int_{-1}^{1}|1-t^2||u(t)|\,dt\\
&\leq ||u||_{\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)\,dt=\frac{4}{3}||u||_{\infty}.
\end{align}
$$
And therefore, $||f||_{\infty}\leq 4/3$. And on the other hand, for $u(t)=1$ for $t\in [-1,1]$ we obtain
$$f(u)=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)\,dt=\frac{4}{3},$$
thereby, $\frac{4}{3}=|f(u)|\leq ||f||_{\infty}\cdot ||u||_{\infty}=||f||_{\infty}$, since $||u||_{\infty}=1$ when $u(t)=1$ for all $t$. So, at the end we end up with $||f||_{\infty}=4/3$.